# How exactly is this function an example of a char to int conversion?

Tags: c, type-conversion, kernighan-and-ritchie

The book *The C Programming Language* by Kernighan and Ritchie, second edition states on page 43 in the chapter about *Type Conversions*:

> Another example of `char` to `int` conversion is the function `lower`, which maps a single character to lower case *for the ASCII character set*. If the character is not an upper case letter, `lower` returns returns it unchanged.
>
> ```
> /* lower: convert c to lower case; ASCII only */
> int lower(int c)
> {
>     if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
>         return c + 'a' - 'A';
>     else
>         return c;
> }
> ```

It isn't mentioned explicitly in the text so I'd like to make sure I understand it correctly: The conversion happens when you call the `lower` function with a variable of type `char`, doesn't it? Especially, the expression

```
c >= 'A'
```

has nothing to do with a conversion from `int` to `char` since a character constant like `'A'`
is handled as an `int` internally from the start, isn't it? Edit: Or is this different (e.g. a character constant being treated as a `char`) for ANSI C, which the book covers?

Comment: No, the conversion they are talking about happens *inside* the functuon body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character constants have type `int`, as you expected, so you are correct that there are no promotions to `int` in this function.

Any promotion that may occur would happen if a variable of type `char` is passed to this function, and this is most likely what the text is referring to.

The type of character constants is `int` in both the current [C17 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) (section 6.4.4.4p10):

> An integer character constant has type
>   `int`

And in the [C89 / ANSI C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html) (section 3.1.3.4 under Semantics):

> An integer character constant has type `int`

The latter of which is what K&R Second Edition refers to.

Comment: K&R precedes the C standard. Is there reason to believe that, in their text, the type of `'a'` was `int` and not `char`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil On page 37 the book says: "A *character constant* is an integer, written as one character within single quotes, such as `'x'`". I'm not sure if "is an integer" means "is of type `int`"?

Comment: @efie: `char`, `short`, `int`, and `long` are all integer types, and an integer is just a value, so I do not think their reference to a character as an integer is informative.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Regarding your first comment: On page two the book says: "The second edition of *The C Programming Language* describes C as defined by the ANSI standard."

Answer (score 4):

K&R C is old.  Really old.  Many particulars of K&R C are no longer true in up-to-date standard C.

In stadard, up-to-date C11, there is no conversion to/from `char` in the function you posted:

```
/* lower: convert c to lower case; ASCII only */
int lower(int c)
{
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        return c + 'a' - 'A';
    else
        return c;
}
```

The function accepts `int` arguments as `int c`, and per [**6.4.4.4 Character constants** of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4), character literals are of type `int`.

Thus the entire `lower` function, as posted, under C11 deals entirely with `int` values.

The conversion, if any, is may be done when the function is called:

```
char upperA = 'A`;

// this will implicitly promote the upperA char
// value to an int value
char lowerA = lower( upperA );
```

Note that this is one of the differences between C and C++.  In C++, character literals are of type `char`, not `int`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if a character constant was of type `int` in ANSI C as well? Or was it of type `char` which would add another explanation?

Comment: Nothing whatsoever has changed about this function since C89.

Answer (score 2):

> How exactly is this function an example of a `char` to `int` conversion?

```
/* lower: convert c to lower case; ASCII only */
int lower(int c) {
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        return c + 'a' - 'A';
    else
        return c;
}
```

It is not an example of a `char` to `int` conversion - technically incorrect by the author.

---

The text goes on to discuss `tolower(c)` as an alternative to `lower()` as it "works" correctly even if [A -Z] are not consecutively encoded as in [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).

What is not discussed, is that `tolower()` functions and others (`is...()`) are only specified for `int` values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.  C11 §7.4 1.  Other values invoke *undefined behavior* (UB).

It is this requirement that makes these Standard C library functions *conceptually*  `char` to `int` conversions as only values in the (about) `char` range are specified and the result is `int`.

---

Now look at code where **`char` conversion does occur**.

```
void my_strtolower1(char *s) {
  while (*s) {
    *s = lower(*s);  // conversion `char` to `int` and `int` to `char`.
    s++;
  }
} 

void my_strtolower2(char *s) {
  while (*s) {
    *s = tolower(*s); // conversion `char` to `int` and `int` to `char`.
    s++;
  }
} 

void my_strtolower3(char *s) {
  while (*s) {
    // conversion `char` to `unsigned char` to `int` and `int` to `char`.
    *s = tolower((unsigned char) *s); 
    s++;
  }
}
```

`my_strtolower1()` well defined, yet not functionally correct on rare machines where `[A-Z,a-z]` are not consecutive.

`my_strtolower2()` expected functionality except technically undefined behavior when `*s < 0` (and not `EOF`).

`my_strtolower3()` expected functionality without UB when `*s < 0`.